# Is $\ln(\sum X)$ for Bernoulli $X$ is asymptotically normal?

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions

I struggle to prove one statement from the Problem 3, Problem set 4 of the
MIT course 18.650. Statistics for Applications. [PDF](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-650-statistics-for-applications-fall-2016/assignments/MIT18_650F16_PSet4.pdf)

This is question "4.": Prove that $f(\bar{X}_n)$ is asymptotically normal

Basically, what I have to do here is to prove, that for a random variable $X \sim  \textrm{Bernoul}(p)$, the estimator $\lambda$

$$
\lambda = f(\bar{X}_n) = - \frac{1}{z}\ln\left(\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n X_i}{n}\right)
$$

asymptotically normal (for $n \rightarrow\infty$). Where $z$ is some threshold, that can be assumed to be a constant.

Since 
$$
\bar{X}_n \underset{n\rightarrow\infty}{\sim}\textrm{Norm}(\mu_1,\sigma_1^2)
$$
by the LLN, it seams to me very surprising, that also 
$$
\ln(\bar{X}_n) \underset{n\rightarrow\infty}{\sim}\textrm{Norm}(\mu_2,\sigma_2^2)
$$
could be true.

My question is, how to prove, that $f(\bar{X}_n)$ is asymptotically normal.

Comment: Delta method: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delta_method

Comment: For all $n$ you have $\mathbb P(\bar{X}_n=0)>0$ and thus $\mathbb P(\ln(\bar{X}_n)=-\infty)>0$, so $\mathbb E[\ln(\bar{X}_n)] = -\infty$.  This means that even if you get some sort of convergence in distribution to a Gaussian after a location-scale adjustment then you need to be careful with any conclusions you draw

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By the CLT,
$$
\sqrt{n}(\bar{X}_n-p)\xrightarrow{d}N(0,p(1-p)).
$$
Now use the [delta method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delta_method), which implies that
$$
\sqrt{n}(\ln(\bar{X}_n)-\ln(p))\xrightarrow{d}N(0,(1-p)/p).
$$